# Accordion Tab Not Display when the Input is checked

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to ask if what is the wrong in my code here, what I wanted to do is the content will display block when when the input is checked, and also sometimes the input is delay can someone help. Thank You so much

Code is here - https://codepen.io/romblondev/pen/jOXRora

I tried to target the

```
#dashboard:checked ~ .accordion-content #one-tab-content,
#grading:checked ~ .accordion-content #two-tab-content,
#student:checked ~ .accordion-content #three-tab-content,
#teachers:checked ~ .accordion-content #four-tab-content,
#subject:checked ~ .accordion-content #five-tab-content,
#department:checked ~ .accordion-content #six-tab-content,
#faculty:checked ~ .accordion-content #seven-tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

but still not working

Comment: Please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/2518285) and then edit your question to improve it.